# Python, unlist array in DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with 1 column

inside each row of this column I have a `np.array` object with `3` elements

Is there a way to unlist this array and create a DataFrame with 3 columns for easy manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was already asked and answered here: 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Anyway, let's say your dataframe looks like this

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [ np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]), np.array([7, 8, 9])]})
df
```

[image]

Create New dataframe df1, converting column A of original df as a list

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], data = list(df['A']))
df1
```

[image]